# Do stores on Takeshita street open the 1st of January?

Tags: japan, tokyo, public-holidays

1st of January is normally a holiday in Japan. However Takeshita Street is a popular tourist destination. Will stores be open on Takeshita Street on the 1st of January?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**
Some, if not most, stores are open.

**Long Answer**
Note that I haven't visited Harajuku on New Year's, so my information is second-hand, and most of my references are in Japanese.

Looking through Yahoo Q&As (like [this](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1352113188) and [this](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11180568766)), I'm getting mixed signals: some says a lot of shops are open, and others say most are closed (also note that some of the posts are old, so the situation may have changed).

A quick search tells me that food shops are open, and larger malls like [Laforet Harajuku](https://www.laforet.ne.jp/en/) and [Omotesando Hills](https://www.omotesandohills.com/) are also open. I checked a few stores on the [list](https://www.takeshita-street.com/shop.html) (requires a good amount of digging) and most of them had regular or holiday hours. One or two were closed (probably looked up 7 or 8 stores).

Looking at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kbNhqRfTDy4) of Takeshita in 2017 (taken around 15:00), I believe it's safe to say that a lot of the stores were open for business. Someone with first-hand experience would have a better say than me, though.

Also note that Harajuku station is one of the closest stops from Meiji Jingu Shrine, so it will be crowded on New Year's.

Comment: This is a very complete answer. It is confirmed that on January 1st 2020 most Takeshita shops were open and the market was absolutely crowded.